# Отзыв про недочеты в переводе заглавной страницы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> Если вы видите недочет, пожалуйста, оставьте отзыв на Мете.

Оставляю! Заглавная страница наводит на грустные размышления.

> Зачем <s>нужно</s> нужен коллективный перевод?
>
> Перевод - <s>от части</s> отчасти творческое занятие.
>
> Переводя <s>фразы ошибок</s> сообщения об ошибках, <s>на вроде</s> подобные... следует <s>использовать</s> указывать причину <s>ошибку вначале</s> ошибки в начале сообщения. То есть, <s>В</s>верно: "При отправке возникла ошибка"<s>,</s>; <s>_не верно__</s> неверно: "Возникла ошибка при отправке".
>
> Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с <s>текущем</s> текущим обсуждением терминов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за замечания! Указанные вами недочеты поправили.